# Switching pages in an android application

Tags: android

im wondering what is the best way to pass between pages in my app.

right now i have made linear layout classes for each page.

I dont know if i should make activity class for each page and every button will open a new page as a new activity,
Or should i do everything in the Main Activity and every button will set the layout of the Main Activity as the requested page.

What is the best way? Anybody have another way that i didn't menchend?

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of page? Normally, we use Activity to hold different logical task, for Pad app, you can use Fragments for more dynamic area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [intents](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html), [they appear in the training section](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) of the Android webpage and they are relatively easy to use to pass data around the screens/activities.

As always it's a good idea to look at current [samples](http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html) to see how other developers do that kind of work.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) you can create an app with only one activity, which is dynamically adding or removing Fragments from the View